# How to change text direction in richtextbox?

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I have RichTextBox .. if I opened a word 2003 ( or 2007 ) document and copied any table and paste it in it, the table's direction became Left-to-Right .. it reverse :

EX : this

```
---------------
|     TOP     |
---------------
|   1  |   2  |
---------------
```

after copy and paste in richtextbox became this :

```
---------------
|     TOP     |
---------------
|   2  |   1  |
---------------
```

is there any way to fix this ??

Thanx in advance

**update :**
I tried to save word file as .rtf and opened it with "Notepad++" then I copied the rtf code and put it in richtextbox.rtf property, I got the table but with same problem

Comment: No repro.  Does this happen when you run wordpad.exe?  Where do you live?

Answer (score 0):

Try [RightToLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.righttoleft.aspx) property to achieve what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer Here :
[Why isn't the richtextbox displaying this table properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928853/why-isnt-the-richtextbox-displaying-this-table-properly)

You need to create a new version of RichTextBox, and for those ( like me ) who don't know how to create custom control you'll find this article very useful :
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/cutebutton.aspx