# Is there an issue with this RTF sample?

Tags: c#, rtf

I am doing an [override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148731/richtextbox-does-not-display-all-data-when-i-override-createparams) of RichTextBox to tell it to use the newest RTF assembly available.  I have RTF which displays well in MS word.  The same RTF is mal-aligned in a table when viewed in my custom RichTextBox.

Example

[image]

Is there any issue with this RTF formatting that will cause this to occur?

```
{\rtf1\ansi\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0 Arial;}{\f1 Courier New;}}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\lang1033\f0\fs20 
{\pard\f0\ul\b Fingerstick Glucose\b0 : Collected: 8/29/2012 5:44:00 AM\ulnon\f0\par}
\par\pard\lang1033\f0\fs20 
{\trowd
\cellx4000
\cellx9500
 Fingerstick Glucose\intbl\cell
 125 mg/dL\intbl\cell
\row}
```

}

**UPDATE**

This greatly simplified RTF has the same issue.  "cell 1" floats above and out of the table.

```
{\rtf1\ansi\deff0
\trowd
\cellx1000
\cellx2000
\cellx3000
cell 1\intbl\cell
cell 2\intbl\cell
cell 3\intbl\cell
\row
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\intbl` needs to come before the text.

```
{\rtf1\ansi\deff0 
\trowd 
\cellx1000 
\cellx2000 
\cellx3000 
\intbl cell 1\cell 
\intbl cell 2\cell 
\intbl cell 3\cell 
\row 
}
```